# Arduino I2C DS1621 commands

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a question about the DS1621 (arduino):

What commands and parameters must be sent  to the pin 3 (TOut) so that this shows a temperature greater than 25 Celsius on HIGH?

I want to use the Wire lib. 
Is this right or what else do I need?

```
 #define DEV_ID 0x90 >> 1 
 int tempC = 25;  //for 25 Celsius 

 void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);           
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(DEV_ID);           // connect to DS1621 
  Wire.send(0xAC);                          
  Wire.send(0x02);                          
  Wire.beginTransmission(DEV_ID);           
  Wire.send(0xEE);                          
  Wire.endTransmission();
 }

 void loop() {
  tempC = Wire.receive();
  Serial.print(tempC);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tout is "Thermostat output. Active when temperature exceeds TH; will reset when 
temperature falls below TL."

So you must set TL and TH. The control byte must be sent for the value is send

[A1h] [value for TH]
[A2h] [value for TL]

Luckily for us 25 degrees is a value they gave as 0x19 or 00011001
so my code would look like this

```
 Wire.begin();
 Wire.beginTransmission(DEV_ID);           //I am talking to you
 Wire.send(0xA1);                          //I want to change TH
 Wire.send(0x19);                          //Value of 25
 Wire.endTransmission();

 Wire.beginTransmission(DEV_ID);           //I am talking to you
 wire.send(0xA2);                          //I want to change TL
 Wire.send(0x19);                          //value of 25                      
 Wire.endTransmission();
```

You have add/keep the rest of you code, but see if that does the trick.

Here is the data sheet http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1621.pdf